# What is the best way to use the lib Ionic.Zip (DotNetZip) and SshNet to download a directory via SFTP/SCP directly to a zip file

Tags: c#, zip, sftp

What is the best way to use the lib Ionic.Zip (DotNetZip) and SshNet to download a directory via SFTP/SCP directly to a zip file, I would like to do this without running out of memory and if possible without having to download it to the local disk first.

I made this code but I'm having memory overflow problems.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
            var connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo("192.168.133.13", "user",
                                        new PasswordAuthenticationMethod("user", "pass"));
            var client = new SftpClient(connectionInfo);            
            client.Connect();
            DownloadDirectoryAsZip(client, "/var/www/dart/intranetbrowser", @"C:\MyCsharpProjects\fsbackup\download.zip");
            client.Dispose();  
            
}
public static void DownloadDirectoryAsZip(SftpClient sftpClient, string sourceRemotePath, string destLocalPath)
{
            ZipFile zip = new ZipFile();      
            DownloadDirectoryAsZipRec(zip, sftpClient, sourceRemotePath);
            zip.Save(destLocalPath);
            zip.Dispose();
}
private static void DownloadDirectoryAsZipRec(ZipFile zip,SftpClient sftpClient, string sourceRemotePath)
{
         
            IEnumerable<SftpFile> files = sftpClient.ListDirectory(sourceRemotePath);
            foreach (SftpFile file in files)
            {
                if ((file.Name != ".") && (file.Name != ".."))
                {
                    string sourceFilePath = sourceRemotePath + "/" + file.Name;
                  
                    if (file.IsDirectory)
                    {
                        DownloadDirectoryAsZipRec(zip,sftpClient, sourceFilePath);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();                                               
                        sftpClient.DownloadFile(sourceFilePath, memoryStream);                                                
                        zip.AddEntry(sourceFilePath, memoryStream);                        
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks good. Though it does not look like the Ionic.Zip can write the zip file continuously to the disk. So you probably cannot avoid keeping whole ZIP file in memory. But you can save some memory by doing `using (var s = sftpClient.OpenRead(sourceFilePath)) { zip.AddEntry(sourceFilePath, s); }` Though that might have download performace impacts.

Comment: I got a solution using System.IO.Compression as suggested here https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/issues/948 @Martin Prikryl

Comment: Sure, that works. But you have asked about Ionic.Zip.